# How to store date and time in UTC in SQL Server datetimeoffset with JDBC

Tags: sql-server, java-8, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, datetimeoffset

My Spring Boot application requires to store and express all dates and times in UTC, so the POJOs in the application use `OffsetDateTime` data type and the SQL Server 2016 database use `datetimeoffset(7)` column type. The JDBC library is `ms-sql 6.1.0.0`, a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver. Version of JVM is Oracle Java 8.

I am using Spring JDBC and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to implement the DAO implementation class. *No JPA, ORM, etc.*

When inserting a record, I use the `jdbcTemplate.update(String, Map<String,Object>)`. This appears to be working, *except* that values saved in the database are not the same as what I supplied via the Map. For e.g. `namedParameters.put("record_datetime", someEntity.getRecordDatetime());` where that object's `recordDatetime` property holds the value `2018-05-31T13:20:01Z` is saved in the database as `2018-05-31T20:20:01.0000000+00:00`. I happen to be in a GMT-7 timezone, but the property uses a datatype of `OffsetDataTime` with no offset, i.e. it is GMT essentially.

I have a bigger issue on hand when trying to retrieve the value from the database. I use `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(String, Map<String,?>, RowMapper<T>)` and in the RowMapper, I use `resultSet.getObject("record_datetime", OffsetDateTime.class)`. This results in an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: This operation is not supported.
```

I tried using `OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(resultSet.getObject("record_datetime", Instant.class), ZoneId.of("UTC"))`. Same exception as above is thrown.

This has to be a very common requirement, to be able to store values in UTC, and/or with offset values. In other applications, I employed `java.util.Date` and either `java.sql.Date` (or `java.sql.Timestamp`) in the DAO to persist date or date-time values, and that generally worked well. I am somehow finding this much harder to implement.

Comment: One obvious issue is that `CallableStatement` has no explicit support for `OffsetDateTime`, so it's likely some conversion to either `Timestamp` or even `String` is happening under the covers. Even if you bypassed that, it appears the MS JDBC drivers have no support for `OffsetDateTime`, since the most recent docs [still list a `microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset` being used in the low-level methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/setdatetimeoffset-method-sqlservercallablestatement). I don't know if or how you could connect Spring to this native type somehow.